# For Loop Stuck?

Tags: java, for-loop

I'm a beginner in java. Is there any way of knowing if the variable `n` never reaches `(boats-3)`? The method `placeShip` has a `while` loop in it, so this `for` can get stuck before `n` reaches `boats-3`.

```
for (int n = 0; n < boats - 3; n++)
{
    this.opcao = rand.nextInt(3);

    if (opcao == 0)
    {
        placeShip1(grelha);
    }
    else if (opcao == 1)
    {
        placeShip2(grelha);
    }
    else
    {
        placeShip4(grelha);
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the value of boats when you start the loop?

Comment: @user3685285 Portuguese is his main language. It should be obvious that English isn't his main language if you look at his code.

Comment: @user3685285 this is not really a constructive and appropriate comment, is it?

Comment: Is the variable `boats` a class member or a local variable in this method? If a class member do you make anything with it in methods `placeShip`? If it is not a class member, but just a local variable, methods placeShip cannot change it. `n` is also a local variable and cannot be changed by other method. So `n` will increment till it reaches `n==boats-3` but the last entry into the cycle will be when `n==boats-4`.

Comment: I think we would need to see the implementation of your placeShip functions to see if and how they mutate boats

Comment: @QBrute Had to read it like 3 times. Editing disabled. It's confusing. Coding is about communication too.

Answer (score 2):

This is the wrong question to ask. You should be asking yourself, how do I ensure that the while loops in placeShip never get stuck. For example:

```
while (true)
{
    if (no more boats left to place) { break; }
    else { place another boat; }
}
```

If you write well designed code, you'll never need to ask yourself such things.

Answer (score 1):

The variable `n` will never reach the value `boats - 3` inside of your loop since your for loop says `n < boats - 3`

Answer (score 1):

I think you wanted to know if the program was stuck in one of the `placeship()` functions. You can put two print statements before and after each `placeship()` function to check if the program ever jumps out of the function. The code would be something like this:

```
if (opcao == 0)
{
  System.out.println("n is " + n);
  System.out.println("Before placeShip1");
  placeShip1(grelha);
  System.out.println("After placeShip1");
}
```

Do the same thing for the other two `placeShip()`. Then you should be able to see where the program is stuck.

Comment: `n` will be equal to `boats - 3` when the cycle is complete and execution goes to next statement. Of course with this value it will not go **into** the cycle. So telling that it will **never** reach is a bit confusing.

Comment: @TodorSimeonov sorry for the confusion, I edited my post.